# Error when generating short link with FirebaseDynamicLinks with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

Recently when i update my flutter app and firebase_dynamic_links package to 4.0.7
I have a function to generate a short link, but now this function doesn't work any more and get this error :
Error [firebase_dynamic_links/unknown] FDL domain is missing. Set with setDomainUriPrefix() or setDynamicLinkDomain(),
my code is :

```
final shortUri = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(
        DynamicLinkParameters(link: uri, uriPrefix: ''),
        shortLinkType: ShortDynamicLinkType.unguessable);
    return shortUri.shortUrl;
```

Please help me and thanks in advance

```
final shortUri = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(
        DynamicLinkParameters(link: uri, uriPrefix: ''),
        shortLinkType: ShortDynamicLinkType.unguessable);
    return shortUri.shortUrl;
```